# .getDay() strange behaviour

Tags: javascript

There is an example

```
console.log((new Date(2013, 02, 24)).getDay(), 24) // => 0 24
console.log((new Date(2013, 02, 25)).getDay(), 25) // => 1 25
console.log((new Date(2013, 02, 26)).getDay(), 26) // => 2 26
console.log((new Date(2013, 02, 27)).getDay(), 27) // => 3 27
console.log((new Date(2013, 02, 28)).getDay(), 28) // => 4 28
console.log((new Date(2013, 03, 01)).getDay(), 01) // => 1 1
console.log((new Date(2013, 03, 02)).getDay(), 02) // => 2 2
```

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay, method `getDay()`

> Returns the day of the week for the specified date according to local
>   time.
>
> The value returned by getDay is an integer corresponding to the day of
>   the week: 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday, 2 for Tuesday, and so on.

It doesn't seem to be true for the two last results. I  expect the output to be like the following

```
0 24
1 25
2 26
3 27
4 28
5 1
6 2
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When setting the date, passing 2 means March as it is 0 based. If you use 1 for february it will work as expected.

Quoting https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

> **month**
>       Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December.